# How to send ajax call to server without expecting a return result?

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I   pass inputs to actionResult which will use it to  create a new object and insert it to database using entityFramework and dont want to return anything.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $("#Add").click(function () {
            var EmployeeeId = $("#EmployeeId").val();
            var Phone =$("#Phone").val();
            var Email = $("#Email").val();
            var Address = $("#Address").val(); 
        var UserModel =
{
    "EmployeeId": EmployeeeId,
    "Phone": Phone,
    "Address": Address,
    "Email": Email

};    $.ajax({url: '@Url.Action("AddNewContactList","Home")',

            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",

            data: JSON.stringify(UserModel),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',


                        success: function (result) {

                           //Doesnt Matter

                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                            alert("Failed");
                        }
```

And here is my Controller Code with the controller action being called

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNewContactList(ContactList c)
    {
        DbContext m = new DbContext();
        m.ContactList.Add(c);
        m.SaveChanges();
        return View();
}
```

Comment: Your title says you're not expecting a result. The first line of your question says you are. Which is it?

Comment: what is the that you want to happen?

Comment: So just ignore the response... Or change the method on the server to not return anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the url & data attribute in ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourURL",
  data: yourData
});
```

Comment: I will try it and inform u.

Comment: What if a want to still perform another action, but not dependent on the data.  For instance display a success message

Answer (score 1):

Return void in your action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public void AddNewContactList(ContactList c)
{
    DbContext m = new DbContext();
    m.ContactList.Add(c);
    m.SaveChanges();
}
```